# Dont know how to solve the error in void-function

Tags: c, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define e 2.71828

float fct( float x, int n )
{
    float f=0;
    switch(n){
        case 1: f=(4*x-1); break;
        case 2: f=(sin(3*x)); break;
        case 3: f=((1.0/7.0)+(1.0/x)); break;
        case 4: f=(pow(e,x)-2*x+3); break;
        case 5: f=(pow((x-2),3)+2); break;
    }
    return f;
}
;

void nullstelle(float a, float b, float g, int n)
{
    float fm, fa, fb, m;
    int anzit=0;
    fa=fct(a,n);
    fb=fct(b,n);
    while (b-a>g && fm!=0)
    {
        m=((a+b)/2);
        fm=fct(m,n);
        if (fa*fm < 0)
        {
            b=m;
            fb=fm;
        }
        else
        {
            a=m;
            fa=fm;
        }
        anzit++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float a, b, g, m;
    int n, anzit;

    printf( "Fuer n=1: f=(4*x-1)\n" );
    printf( "Fuer n=2: f=(sin(3*x))\n" );
    printf( "Fuer n=3: f=(1/7+1/x)\n" );
    printf( "Fuer n=4: f=(pow(e,x)-2*x+3)\n" );
    printf( "Fuer n=5: f=(pow((x-2),3)+2)\n" );
    printf( "\nFunktionszahl n eingeben:\n" );
    scanf( "%i", &n );

    printf( "Intervallgrenzen: Untere Grenze a und Obere Grenze b eingeben:\n" );
    scanf( "%f %f", &a, &b );

    printf( "Benoetigte Genauigkeit g eingeben: [-g;0] [0;g]\n" );
    scanf( "%f", &g );

    printf( "Nullstelle: %f\n", nullstelle( a, b, g, n) );
    printf( "Anzahl der Iterationsschritte: %i\n", anzit );

    if (fct(nullstelle(a,b,g,n), n)!=0)
        printf("Keine genaue Nullstelle gefunden\n");
    else
        printf("ok\n");

    return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

So now the Debugger says: `invalid use of void expression`. I'm stuck. Would be really nice if you could help. 
P.S.: I have to use void.

Comment: Think: what is the value of `nullstelle(a,b,g,n)` in the expression `if (fct(nullstelle(a,b,g,n), n)!=0)`? How is C supposed to evaluate this?

Comment: You know rather than writing "Hello" about 50 times to fill out the space, you could of used it to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: So it's the *debugger* that complains, not the compiler? When? Where? What are you doing? Also, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you are trying to access varible from nullstelle function which is returns null. that might be a problem ?

Comment: @YiğitYüksel That function does not return anything. And what do you mean with "null" anyway?

Comment: @Olaf not null, void sorry

Comment: @YiğitYüksel: `void` is not a valid object type, so no, it does not return `void` either. (and please use markdown!)

Comment: @Olaf, `void` is not a valid object type, but I think it's okay to say a function returns void, meaning the function's return type is `void`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: This might be true for other languages, but it is not for C (and C++). `void` is a grammatical element and **not** a type it returns. Using such a function as operator of an expression invokes undefined behaviour. Better think of such functions as Pascal "procedures". "returning something" is not the same as "returning nothing".

Comment: @Olaf, Well if the function's return type is `int`, I would say the "function returns an int", whereas if the function's return type is `void`, I would say "the function returns void", not "returns _a_ void". I.e., I'm using the word "void" to mean "absence of a thing" or "nothing", not "an empty thing" or "an object of type `void`".

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in

```
if (fct(nullstelle(a,b,g,n), n)!=0)
```

`nullstelle` is a function that returns nothing, but `fct` is a function that requires a float parameter and an integer paramager.

The function `fct` is not receiving the float parameter. You need to reexamine the functions.

Also,

```
printf( "Nullstelle: %f\n", nullstelle( a, b, g, n) );
```

expects a float parameter, but the function only returns `void`

Comment: There is another problem in function `nullstelle` itself. The value of variable `fm` may be used before it has been initialized. I'm guessing that `nullstelle` is supposed to return the final value of `fm`.

Comment: ... Or rather more likely, I'm guessing `nullstelle` should be returning the final value of `m`.